# Model relationships in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've got MySQL tables for site cart:

```
Cart:
id | user 

Cart_goods:
cart_id | good_id | good_type

Details:
id | name

Appliances:

id | name
```

Class Cart, which contains goods:

```
class Cart extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'cart';
 protected $fillable = ['user', 'sum', 'profit', 'discount'];
 protected $guarded = ['user'];

 public function goods()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Good');
 }
}
```

Class Good, which can be Detail or Appliance and relative to cart by cart_id:

```
class Good extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'cart_goods';
 protected $types = [
    'Detail' => 'App\Models\Detail',
    'Appliance' => 'App\Models\Appliance'
 ];
 public $primaryKey = 'cart_id';

 public function good()
 {
    return $this->morphTo();
 }
}
```

Detail class:

```
class Detail extends Model {
 use SoftDeletes;

 protected $morphClass = 'Detail';
 protected $table = 'details';
 protected $fillable = ['article', 'name', 'photo', 'price_procurement', 'price_retail', 'serial', 'location_id', 'type_id', 'appliance_id', 'comment', 'for'];
 protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
 protected $guarded = [];

 public function goods()
 {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Good', 'good');
 }
}
```

And i need to get all appliances and details in cart. How can i do it by using ORM?

Comment: Have you already wrote your models? with belongsto or hasmany relations?

Comment: @GiuServ, i've edited a question and added models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this, problem was in model name, i was writing it to DB like Detail and Appliance, but i was need to use

```
Relation::morphMap([
   'detail' => 'App\Models\Detail',
   'appliance' => 'App\Models\Appliance',
]);
```

In AppServiceProvider class.

Answer (score 2):

Use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). Assuming that relationship method names are `cartGoods`, `details` and `appliances`, that `details` are details of a cart and that you've defined the relationships right:

```
Card::where('id', $id)
    ->with('cartGoods.appliances', 'details')
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Method 1:** If you have a $cart model instance

```
$cart->load('goods.good');
```

**Method 2:** If you need all appliances and details from cart by card ID

```
Cart::where('id', $cartId)->with('goods.good')->first();
```